# How can i capture a mouse clicks onto the main Window in a child class

Tags: python, pyqt5, mouseclick-event

I would like to capture mouse clicks onto the MainWindow in a child class of the application.
I've tried the following but without success:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class BaseView(object):
    def __init__(self,parent, page=None):
        self.parent = parent
        self.page = page
    @abstractmethod
    def preprare_view(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def clean_up_view(self):
        pass

class FooView(BaseView):
    def __init__(self, parent, page):
        super(FooView, self).__init__(parent, page)
        self.parent = parent
        
    def mousePressEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        print(parent.QMouseEvent.pos())
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        cursor = QtGui.QCursor()
        print(parent.cursor.pos())

class Example(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):
        self.foo = "fooview"
        self.Foo = FooView(self,self.foo)
        qbtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Quit', self)
        qbtn.resize(qbtn.sizeHint())
        qbtn.move(50, 50)
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 1024, 768)
        self.setWindowTitle('Quit button')
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.show()
def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm wondering how I can capture the mouse clicks in the `FooView` child class - is that even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>There is terminology that the OP uses that is confusing, for example FooView is a child class of BaseView but that has nothing to do with Qt so it is irrelevant for this case so I will omit that class and show the example of how another class can obtain information about the click event of a widget.</sub>

The logic is to create a class that inherits from QObject and apply an event filter to the other widget, then override the eventFilter method where the events of the widget are obtained.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class MouseObserver(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, widget):
        super(MouseObserver, self).__init__(widget)
        self._widget = widget
        self.widget.installEventFilter(self)

    @property
    def widget(self):
        return self._widget

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self.widget:
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
                print(event.pos(), QtGui.QCursor.pos())
            elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:
                print(event.pos(), QtGui.QCursor.pos())
        return super(MouseObserver, self).eventFilter(obj, event)


class Example(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.observer = MouseObserver(self)

        qbtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Quit", self)
        qbtn.resize(qbtn.sizeHint())
        qbtn.move(50, 50)

        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 1024, 768)
        self.setWindowTitle("Quit button")
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.show()


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```